# Page tables in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, paging, osdev

Question 1 :- During the booting process, Linux creates the page tables. However, when a new process is executed, it also has its own page table. How are these two tables different?

Question 2 :- On x86 arch, Linux uses a well defined scheme (which includes Page directory, page table entries and likewise) to translate the linear address to physical address.
Suppose we have a linear address X in the process address space A which when translated using the page tables corresponds to physical address Y. There is some other process B which also has valid linear address X belonging to its own address space. Now if process B wants to access X, would X once again corresponds to the same physical address Y?

Comment: Please edit this so that you ask two separate questions, not "two questions in one".

Comment: this sounds pretty much like homework, doesn't it?

Comment: @knittl: Perhaps, but I suspect that any answers here will be far beyond what the "teacher" wanted, and may infact contract the class notes. ("Linux uses a well defined scheme"?  Just one? Wasn't this changed recently?)

Comment: @David +1 for pointing out that no one is actually trying to answer the question apart from editing and adding comments.

Comment: @knittl: It may sound like homework question and I agree. I am trying to understand the MMU part of Linux and these questions I posted here are some of the initial doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** Page tables aren't created only at boot.  A new page table is created every time a processes is forked.  The new tables follow a template set up by the kernel at boot, but each is an independent data structure that can change per-process.  They generally differ to allow each process to have its own working memory that only it can access.

**Question 2:** No, and this behavior is one of the reasons paging is used in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Their permissions are different.

Question 2: No.

You might want to check this out too, if you're really curious and not just looking for easy answers for your homework: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory